# How to delete a node & its childs in XML

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, mfc, msxml

i am facing some problem in Deleting a Node from XML.

Here is the schema of my XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<file>
    <header Description="Lovely Tool"></header>

  <ToolPath>C:\MyDocs\MyTool\</ToolPath>

   <ToolDetails>
    <Name>XML Tool</Name>
    <Description>XML parser</Description>
    <Comments>Good Tool for XML</Comments>
  </ToolDetails>
</file>
```

I want to delete the Node `ToolDetails`and its `childs`, i tried like this using MSXML, but its not working,

Here is my code

```
   CString childName;
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr childPtr = NULL;
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr delNode = NULL;
    int i=0;
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodeListPtr  pChildNodeListPtr = NULL;

delNode  = m_pRoot->GetchildNodes()->Getitem(index+2);//m_pRoot is the root ptr
childName=(char*)m_ptrDataBlock->nodeName;
HRESULT hr = m_pRoot->removeChild(delNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Getitem(index+2)` will only return the handle for `index + 2th` item.

for deleting the node you also need to detach the item by calling 
`Getitem(index)->detach()`

Comment: try looking here: http://read.pudn.com/downloads108/sourcecode/windows/dialog/443834/3rdParty/XmlNodeWrapper.cpp__.htm

hth...

Comment: i tried like this "for(i=0;i<pChildNodeListPtr->Getlength();i++)
 {
  childPtr = pChildNodeListPtr->item[i].Detach();
     
  childName = (char*)childPtr->nodeName;
  childName=(char*)childPtr->text;
  hr = childPtr->GetparentNode()-emoveChild(childPtr);

  " i m getting HR NULL :(